# How to use onSnapshot function of Firebase in Angular 8+

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I a trying to listen to my employee collection in Firebase whenever a new user registers. I try something like this

```
  constructor(private firebase: AngularFirestore) {}
  check() {
     return this.firebase.collection('users').onSnapshot()
  }
```

I also try like this

```
check() {
    return this.firebase.firestore().collection('users').onSnapshot()
  }
```

How

Comment: Please clarify what is the issue! How...?

Comment: I want to get a notification when new data come into my documents without a refresh. like any notification panel.

Answer (score 0):

The `onSnapshot` stream is a concept from the regular JavaScript SDK, which AngularFire wraps. You'd normally use the `documentChanges()` or `valueChanges()` observables in AngularFire instead.

But if you want to use `onSnapshot`, you can get it by unwrapping the regular `FirebaseFirestore` object from its `AngularFirestore` wrapper. As far as I can see, that's done by reading the `firestore` property, so:

```
this.firebase.firestore.collection('users').onSnapshot()
```